# How to donate a computer without jeopardizing personal information?

Tags: memory, privacy, forensics

I have an old computer that is no longer working and I want to donate it or perhaps throw it in the trash. However, I don't want people to potentially get my banking account data, usernames/passwords I have entered on the computer, software installed, legal or medical documents, internet browser data, etc. I am going to keep the hard drive, should I do something more to the computer before getting rid of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the PC has an HDD just use https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/ on an USB stick or CD-R/DVD-R and erase the HDD completely. Then all your data is gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep the hard drive in your possession (that is what I read from your question), then there is nothing that a person receiving the computer can get. I assume from your post there is no small SSD drive, but if so, keep it as well.

Motherboard, Memory, CPU and GPU do not hold any information once the computer is powered off. It is all on the hard drive.

So keep the drive and you will be fine. We have done this at customers wishing to donate computers.